# Perimeter-minimizing disks on curved surfaces: is there an asymptotic formula in the limit of small disks?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature

Suppose that I have a smooth curved surface, and I choose an arbitrary point $Q$ on that surface. Say the Gaussian curvature at that point is $K$. What I am wondering is, is there an asymptotic formula for the minimal perimeter $P_{min}$ of a disk of area $A$ which contains point $Q$, in the limit of a very small disk with $AK \ll 1$? What I imagine is something like

$$
P_{min} = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi}}+\text{powers of $K$ or derivatives of $K$ at $Q$}
$$

The zeroth-order term comes from the planar case. My question is:

- Is such an expansion possible at all, and if it is, are any lowest order terms known?

I have searched but I could not find any result of the sort. For geodesic disks, I have used the [Bertrand–Diguet–Puiseux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%E2%80%93Diguet%E2%80%93Puiseux_theorem) to obtain

$$
P_{geo} = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{A}{\pi}} \left( 1 - \frac{AK}{8\pi} \right) + O(\sqrt{A}A^2K^2)
$$
or equivalently
$$
P_{geo}^2 = 4 \pi A - A^2 K + O(A^3K^2)
$$
which implies that a small geodesic disk of a given area will have larger perimeter in a negatively curved region than in a positively curved region. A second, weaker question is therefore

- Does a similar result hold for the small perimeter-minimizing disk? I.e. will $P_{min}$ always be larger for $K<0$ than for $K>0$ in the limit of small area?

Comment: If you don't intend a geodesic disk, what do you mean by a "disk of area $A$"? For something merely diffeomorphic to a disk, there will be no control.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. By "disk" I mean a region enclosed by a closed curve. What do you mean by no control?

Comment: You can make can make arbitrarily wiggly (long) curves enclosing the same area. This is not curvature-related.

Comment: @TedShifrin, doesn't "perimeter minimizing" preclude wiggling? It seems to me that it suffices to consider geodesic discs, since perimeter minimizing implies constant geodesic curvature of the boundary, and asymptotically the boundary of a geodesic disk has constant curvature.

Comment: Sorry, @Deane, I forgot about the minimal. So, yes, a standard variational argument tells us constant geodesic curvature.

Comment: @Deane, by asymptotically, do you mean that, even if the surface is not of constant Gaussian curvature, as you shrink a geodesic disk to a point the geodesic curvature of its boundary tends to a constant? Do you then think that the expansion that I give above for geodesic disks coincides with that for perimeter-minimizing disks up to the order O(KA) that I give?